# Eclipse Plugin: Add whitespaces to label parameter in Command tag

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Trying to have some whitespaces in pop up menu item label. But the spaces were trimmed.

Tried like below in plugin.xml but not able to do so.

```
      <command
          commandId="com.abc.rcp.currency"
          icon="platform:/plugin/com.rcp.icons/com/rcp/icons/dollar_16.png"
          label="Dollar                  $"
          style="push">
       ....
       </command>
```

Note: I dont want to have keybinding here, need to just update the label with white-spaces.

Comment: Trimmed to what? A single space? I get multiple spaces testing on my Mac.

Comment: Yes trimmed to single space..